# Prediction of sales based on previous data

Tags: algorithms

A bit scared to post a question here (math fear syndrome I bet).
I was looking for a way to predict (rough estimation) a next value based on series of previous values. These values are a sales totals for several previous years.

I found few websites i.e. The Online Excyclopedia of Integer Sequences but cannot understand formulas that are given there and how to modify them.

I know that the problem is not easy but was wondering if there is some way to do at least rough estimation of next few values.

An example. Lets say I have previous years sales: 200, 280, 370, 450, 530.
Now I am looking to predict next few value(s).

Regards

Comment: You could run a linear regression on your points.

Comment: Plot the data and see how they look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data seems to be linear:

[image: Data Plot]

You could fit a linear function to the data.

You would get $f(x)=83x+117$.

EDIT:
To do that, you need to find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=a x + b$ minimices the square of the distance to your data points. You can find more information and the formula for $a$ and $b$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression

If you just want to do a quick calculation, you can use [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear+fit+%7B200%2C+280%2C+370%2C+450%2C+530%7D).

If your data seems non linear data, it can be a difficult problem. You can try to fit other simple functions, such as polynomials or exponentials (you can do that with wolfram alpha too). Predicting the behavior of a function based on some data points is studied by [statistical learning theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_learning_theory).

If you have more data or you want to try more complex fits, you should use a programming language such as Mathematica, Matlab, Python or R (the last two are free and open source).

Comment: Not really, to be honest. I have to admit I was looking for an example I can run against the array of values that would return - let's say - few next predictions.
Not sure where 83x and 117 came from.

Comment: I understand so far that I'd need to look for which function could represent my data. So, I can imagine when data would look different than something that can be a linear function other function would need to be used. What if I have values like: 200,300,400,300,400. This wouldn't work?

If that's the case I would need to first calculate which function to use. That seems like not a trivial task.

Comment: Seems like a bummer then. I cannot guarantee that sales will always raise in linear fashion. I've got at least general idea now. Thanks again @mlainz

Answer (score 1):

I found something called Microsoft Time Series Algorithm which is part of Sql Server Analyses Services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174923.aspx

This seems to be the route to take as I am not familiar with higher matt and Sql Server seems to cover exactly what I need.

Thanks for trying to help me.

**Chart example from the page:**

[image]